# Маршрутизация в AngularJS 1.5

Tags: angularjs, маршрутизация, angular-routing, angular, ui-router

Подскажите как реализовать редирект в роутинге AngularJS 1.5

допустим в Angular2+:

```
routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/firstComponent'},
  { path: 'firstComponent', component: FirstComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound' },
];
```

если пытаюсь сделать так в 1.5, то для пути `/` - пусто,
а для `/#/` срабатывает `404`.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);        
$stateProvider
    .state({
        name: '/',
        url: '',
        redirectTo: 'firstComponent',
    })
    .state({
        name: 'firstComponent',
        url: '/firstComponent',
        template: '...',
    })
    .state({
        name:'404',
        url:'/404',
        template: '...'
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('404');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$urlRouterProvider.
when('/', {redirectTo: '/firstComponent'}).
when('/firstComponent', {templateUrl: '...', controller: '...'}).
when('/404', {templateUrl: '...', controller: '...'}).
otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
```